# FQL and/or Graph Calls only return a limited list of users groups - thoughts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I have been playing around with different fql and graphs to get a FULL LIST of user groups. Meaning, my friends list of groups, but it's not working the way I had hoped.

When you use the Facebook Social Search (blue bar search) - Facebook returns all the groups that person has joined, with the exception of "Secret" groups. While trying to attempt that in the api world, it only returned OPEN GROUPS and CLOSED GROUPS I am also a member of with the person.

IE => User1 & User2 are both members = shows closed group.

Is there not a way to get ALL THE GROUPS (without secret) that the user is a member of ?
- Basically, just trying to get a list of groups that are closed and I am not a member of.

Here's my current FQL call:

```
 SELECT gid,name FROM group WHERE gid IN 
(SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid= $userid )
```

This works perfectly for returning "Open" and "Closed (that I am member of too).

Thoughts or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution as well, to get list of user's group. I found out that now facebook only allow app to get list of group that the app belongs to, not the user's group.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

> 6) user_groups permission not required - Apps can now query /USER_ID/groups and it will return the game groups that a user belongs to for that specific app. **If you're asking this permission to get a user's groups, you should consider not asking for the permission anymore** and modify your logic to take into account that the response only returns apps that belong to your app.

Correct me if i'm wrong.